# Efficient way to "gridify" SQLGeography shape

Tags: sql-server, geography-data-type

Read the "Background" below for full details of why I want to achieve this.

Given a shape, I would like to process it in such a way that it conforms to a 0.00001 x 0.00001 degree grid. (This works out to approximately 1m x 1m cells)
All data is SQLGeography data.

For example:

[image]

Would become:

[image]

Notes: You will notice that the expected result has what might be considered unnecessary vertices (like the one marked by the orange pointer) however, without these verticies I find that SQL Server spatial operations like STDifference result in bad shapes (I can provide more details on this if anyone wants).

I've been working on a potential solution but, I'm concerned that my solution is going to be quite slow.
Essentially I was going to:

- break the polygon into line segments
- For each line segment

  - For each latitude value between min lat, max lat, lat + 0.00001

    - Find the intersecting point on the line segment
    - Using the intersecting point, determine the cell coordinates. (Taking into account the direction of the coordinates I can determine which side of the line is the cell I'm interested in.)
  - For each longitude (do the same as I did for latitude)
- Union all the cells to get my outer ring.
- (This part I haven't figured out yet.) Process ring ensuring that there is a coordinate at each lat+0.00001, lng+0.00001 location.

Ultimately, whatever the solution is, I will need to implement it in SQL Server and javascript.
I'm not sure if I can get away with "treating the earth as flat" if some lines could technically be over a km long.

Now, the obvious solution would be to just generate a grid and intersect with it. However, there are 2 problems with that.

1. Storage: People using the app could be anywhere within an 800,000 square km area. This would result in nearly 1 trillion cells and probably close to a TB of storage.
2. Generation time: To generate the grid would take a very long time.

**Background**: I have an application that allows users to draw a shape on a map. This shape can vary in size from a few square meters to hundreds of thousands of square meters.
Currently, they draw the shape free hand and we take the intersection of that shape with the property that they are drawing it on. Multiple shapes can be drawn on a single property and if that occurs we perform a difference so that shapes do not overlap with existing shapes.

The problem we are facing is that we are often left with invalid spatial objects or tiny gaps between shapes or shapes that break other spatial libraries because of vertices being extremely close together. There are dozens of different spatial problems we have with existing freehand/non gridified shapes. We have many hacks to try and fix them but, we are constantly finding more.

Comment: Simply **round** each vertex coordinate to the nearest mutliple of your grid size. Do *not* add vertices; any point set operation (intersection, difference etc) will suffer massively by higher vertex counts. With the fixed significant precision after snapping vertices to the grid you will likely see much better results.

Comment: @geozelot so, I considered this approach but, it has significant problems.
1. Vertices are fine but the lines between them are not. So if I draw another shape that goes up against the line the vertice cannot be moved onto the grid without introducing gaps/overlaps.
2. Without the extra verticies, SQL Geography STDifference leaves artfiacts behind when performing the operation.

Comment: I am aware of the limitations. However, the only *real* solution to this would be to make the frontend aware, and let users only draw shapes that align with existing ones. The gridding approach will brake your application due to the amount of vertices involved.

Comment: @geozelot I will absolutely be making the frontend aware of whatever solution is implemented, as I mentioned in the question the solution will need to be implemented in both SQL and javascript.

I don't think the number of verticies will break the application. I already deal with gps tracks that contain hundreds of thousands of verticies. While they do take longer to perform spacial operations on, it does work.

Comment: Very well, if gridding is what you want; [this](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf) is a general purpose grid traversal implementation based on a Bresenham based supercover algorithm: for each consecutive pair of vertices of your polygon, traverse the grid and generate/collect cell center coordinates based on simple grid math, then reconstruct your polygon edges with these cell centers. Implement this as a middlelayer in your backend application, you'll get sub-second results for Polygons up to 10k vertices at least.

Comment: @geozelot thanks for that. I haven't quite figured out how to apply the algorithm you linked or your simple breakdown of it. For instance you say "traverse the grid" but, this would imply I have a generated grid. Generating the full grid is one of the problems as it is pretty slow. When you say simple grid math are you saying just use a linear function? Would that work for geography data?

Maybe I'm missunderstanding something.

Comment: I just found a more in depth explanation of the algorithm here: https://github.com/cgyurgyik/fast-voxel-traversal-algorithm/blob/master/overview/FastVoxelTraversalOverview.md. Hopefully using this I'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: Good find. Mathematically, gridding is a function of coordinate intervals with respect to a defined origin. So a 'grid' is inherent in coordinate precision; you round every coordinate to a multiple of 0.001 and they get gridded. You can traverse such a 'grid' by algebra only. That's what traversal algorithms are about; real-time in-memory collision detection or motion planning.

Comment: @geozelot yeah so I think I understand what to do now but, I'm fairly certain that this algorithm will not be accurate for geography data as it does not take into account the curvature of the earth. Now, I'm not sure if this inaccuracy will matter yet as the distances I'll be dealing with might be small enough for it to not matter. However, I suspect that if I have to deal with a shape that is 1km in length that I'm going to have incorrect cell selection using this algorithm. I guess I'll find out once I finish implementing the algorithm and test it out!

Comment: Ya, there's no shape that can form a regular grid on a spherical body. Just as a shape drawn on a planar map can not represent the same shape on a sphere. And 0.00001 degree of longitude is roughly equivalent to 1m only at the Equator (and 0m at the poles).

Comment: @geozelot yeah, I understand that 0.00001 degrees is not accurate as you get close to the poles however I only have to deal with one or two states of Australia so, I think it will be "OK" for that. The concern I have is that drawn shapes need to conform to property boundaries. So, if I use "flat" earth math, I'm pretty sure that on large sites I will end up with gaps along the edge.  So coming back to your first response (round verticies) I'm thinking that if I could "densify" my polygons to ensure that there are regular vertices even on straight lines that maybe the rounding idea would work.